# Getting "cannot assign to 'reply' because method group when adding event in outlook add-in

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

Using VSTO 2012 with Outlook 2010 PIA (i.e. version 12), I'm attempting to hook the reply event on a message; but getting a compile error that I am assigning to a method group.  I've seen some other code around the web that uses the casting method below, but it won't compile for me.   The definitiion in the type lib appears to lack the "event" keyword which may be the problem, but not clear to me how to solve.

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
...
void Application_ItemLoad(object Item)
    {
        if (Item is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mi = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
            Outlook.MailItemClass emi = Item as Outlook.MailItemClass;
            emi +=new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler(MyReply);

        }
    }

    private void MyReply(object Response, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        if (Response is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem re = Response as Outlook.MailItem;
            //..
        }
    }
```

sugestions and help appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, typo when i pasted in the code: should be
   emi.Reply+=new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler(MyReply);

Comment: I can't find the interface/object with ItemEvents_Event_Reply.   I suspect i have two issues 1) a MailItem has a "Reply" method but also 2) the typelib for ItemEvents_10 has Reply (with event parameters) listed as a method not an event(?) when i look in the object browser?  Thanks for helping a noob with my first stackoverflow question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
emi +=new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler(MyReply);
```

Currently you're trying to add an event to the object itself - not to a specific event. You want the [`ItemEvents_Event_Reply`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitemclass.itemevents_event_reply%28v=office.14%29.aspx) event (I suspect) in which case you need:

```
emiItemEvents_Event_Reply += MyReply;
```

(Using a simple method group conversion instead of explicitly creating a new handler. Even if you do want to use the `new ...(MyReply)` syntax, a few choice `using` directives would make your code more readable.)

EDIT: Okay, you can use the [`MailItem.Reply`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_event.reply%28v=office.14%29.aspx) event instead:

```
void Application_ItemLoad(object item)
{
    var mailItem = item as Outlook.MailItem;
    if (mailItem != null)
    {
        mailItem.Reply += MyReply;
    }
}
```

Comment: See my additional comments...I made a typo; my original code was
   emi.Reply+=OutlokItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler(MyReply);
I also can't find a method or object in the Outlook object model with ItemEvents_Event_Reply?  thanks for the suggestion; hopefully now that iv'e corrected the error you have some other ideas..

Comment: @toddwseattle: Well then your original code was still missing the `new`. It's neither a method nor an object - it's an event. Follow the documentation link in my answer.

Comment: thanks; but didn't work. ItemEvents_Event_Rply in the MailItem class is a bit of a wild goose chase because we need an interface for the class. found this link [Working with Outlook Events](http://codeidol.com/csharp/c-sharp-in-office/Working-with-Outlook-Events/Outlook-Item-Events/) doing a little more googlin' which was helpful.   See my answer below; but thanks jon for tryin'

Comment: @toddwseattle: Why do you "need an interface for the class"? Which class, and which interface are you using?

Comment: Maybe I'm just not strong enough on C# syntax; so sorry if i explained wrong.  For the correct code snippet the following works:
    `Outlook.MailItem mi;
    ..
      ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mi).Reply += new   Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler(MyReply);`

Comment: @toddwseattle: Okay, but you shouldn't need the cast, and you can use a method group conversion. I'll edit my answer to show that.

Comment: Actually you need the cast to disambiguate from the method group

Comment: @toddwseattle: It's not clear what you mean. Which cast are you talking about? The cast to `Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event`? If so, just change the type of `mailItem` to `Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event` if you really need to.